# Python importing multiple functions from another file, all within a function

Tags: python

Hello I am trying to import my functions from within another file. I have imported everything from that file at the top of my script using `from my_script import *`. However, as I want to call these imported functions from within another function I have imported them individually from within the function; `from my_script import function_1`- this works correctly. But when I try and import all the functions I need rather than just one, `from my_script import function_1, function_2, function_3` and then call it, Python throws the error: cannot import name 'function_1'.

```
def iphone_5_routine():
from create_files import create_display_file_5
print('Please state the issue using one of the following keywords', keywords)
issue = str(input('Issue: '))

if issue == keywords[0]:
    f = open('displaysolutions.txt','r')  #Make a text file with the iPhone display solutions
    lines = f.readlines()
    print(lines[0])
    issue = input('Has the issue been solved?').lower()

    if issue == 'no':
            print(lines[1])
    else:
            print('Thanks for using the phone diagnostics tool')

    issue = input('Has the issue been solved?').lower()
    if issue == 'no':
            print(lines[2])
            create_display_file_5()

    else:
            print('Thanks for using the phone diagnostics tool')

from create_files import create_speaker_file_5
if issue == keywords[1]:
    f = open('speakersolutions.txt','r')  #Make a text file with the iPhone display solutions
    lines = f.readlines()
    print(lines[0])
    issue = input('Has the issue been solved?').lower()

    if issue == 'no':
            print(lines[1])
    else:
            print('Thanks for using the phone diagnostics tool')

    issue = input('Has the issue been solved?').lower()
    if issue == 'no':
            print(lines[2])
            create_speaker_file_5()

    else:
            print('Thanks for using the phone diagnostics tool')
```

This is the function in which I am trying to call within the other script:

```
     from Task_3_developed_script import *

     def create_display_file_5():
     global case_number
     case_number += 1
     global case_numbers
     case_numbers.append(case_number)
     f = open('{0}.txt'.format(case_numbers[0]),"w")
     f.write("Device: Phone  Model: iPhone 5 Problem: Display")
     f.close()
     print('The case has been exported to a file ready for the technician')
     print('The case number is: ',case_number)

    def create_speaker_file_5():
    global case_number
    case_number += 1
    global case_numbers
    case_numbers.append(case_number)
    f = open('{0}.txt'.format(case_numbers[0]),"w")
    f.write("Device: Phone  Model: iPhone 5 Problem: Speakers")
    f.close()
    print('The case has been exported to a file ready for the technician')
    print('The case number is: ',case_number)
```

Comment: Please add your code and your file structure.

Comment: Please add code so thay it will be helpful to understand the problem better.

Comment: You are definitely missing some indentation in your code...

Comment: @PrestonM that was just from where I copy and pasted the code into here, it is all indented correctly